# How does K means method in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

If using k-means method in machine learning approach to grouping the image based on the goodness or quality of photo.
What if there is a new input? whether the method can not be used for such case studies? Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

KMeans doesn't group images based on "goodness".

It just has some numbers and minimizes least squares. That usually won't be related to "goodness".